# Finding all points where g is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

By following theorem 5.2.3 on intro to real analysis by Bartle, this is as far as I got and then I’m stuck. Do I just find the limit as regular or do I need to do something else?

*[chapter5.2 problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEH7P.jpg)See image attached*

Comment: The function $g$ is defined by cases, not as a quotient. Because both $\Bbb{Q}$ and its complement are dense in the domain, the function will be continuous precisely where the two curves intersect. This claim requires some proof, but hopefully that will nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.